# Getting the X Axis value in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get the actual value of the x axis into a string but I can't work out the syntax.

I have just started to develop a demonstration version of the HighCharts, so the example below is what I am altering:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax/grid

(press options to see the code behind this)

I am trying to change the following line of code

`maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+ this.y +' visits',`

This is because my data x axis value is a Month name. Therefore I want to say something like:

`maincontentText: this.x.value +': '+ this.y +' visits',`

It's probably very simple, does anyone know why every permutation I try has failed?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you give a try to `this.x` instead of `this.x.value`? Tell if works for you.

Comment: Yep, I've tried every combination I can think of. I get a mixture of `undefined` or `Object object` as responses.

Comment: `this.x` gives me the array key value, 0, 1, 2 etc. `this.x.value` is undefined, as is `this.x.name`. `this.data[x].value` gives `Object object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you started with has a numeric x-axis, a timeline, `this.x` will be a number (milliseconds from jan 1, 1970) suitable for `Highcharts.dateFormat`.

If you have changed the example to use a categorical x-axis, then you instead find the category in `this.category` so I think this will work:

`maincontentText: this.category +': '+ this.y +' visits',`

Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfKzS/)

Comment: Unbelievable, how did I not try that. I spent at least an hour trying everything else. Thanks, I'm now off to find my dunce cap.

Comment: wondering if this would work this.y - [this.y - 1]

where i am expecting [this.y - 1] to be the previous value of y

any ideas?